# How can I trigger 2 functions simultaneously with onclick?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a banner ad script. I got this script from adsterra ad provider. What I want is this;
When users click on this banner ad script, both the ad will open and the Timer1 will be triggered. How do you think I can do this? I tried creating 2 different functions and calling them with onclick() but only Timer1 is triggered. Banner ad won't open. Please help me ???

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AnaReklam";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MainLayout.cshtml";
}
<title>Fidan Dik</title>
<div class="alert alert-warning bg-warning border-0 alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert" style="text-align:center;">
    <b>*** Her 15 dakikada bir 10 adet fidan dikerek 300 tohum kazanabilirsiniz ***</b>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>

<br />
<br />

<div style="background-color: #8F9BF7; width: 500px; height: 110px;text-align:center; border-radius:50px;margin-left:325px;">
    @if (ViewBag.kalan != 0)
    {
        <button class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-top: 40px; border-radius: 20px;">
            @TempData["ZamanFarkı"] Dk Kaldı
        </button>
    }
    else
    {
        <button onclick="myFunction2(); myFunction()" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top: 40px; border-radius: 20px;">
            <b> Fidan Dik</b>
        </button>
    }
</div>
<br />
@Html.Action("Reklam2", "FidanDik")
<br />
@Html.Action("Reklam3", "FidanDik")
@Html.Action("Reklam4", "FidanDik")
<br />
@Html.Action("Reklam5", "FidanDik")
<br />
@Html.Action("Reklam6", "FidanDik")
<br />
@Html.Action("Reklam7", "FidanDik")
<br />
@Html.Action("Reklam8", "FidanDik")
<br />
@Html.Action("Reklam9", "FidanDik")
<br />
@Html.Action("Reklam10", "FidanDik")
<br />

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        window.location = "/FidanDik/Timer1";
    }
</script>
<script>
    function myFunction2() {
            atOptions = {
                'key' : 'c7cb7e984302b571ae53490b98af1031',
            'format' : 'iframe',
            'height' : 60,
            'width' : 468,
            'params' : { }
    };
            document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http' + (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 's' : '') + '://seekgeographical.com/c7cb7e984302b571ae53490b98af1031/invoke.js"></scr' + 'ipt > ');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you just merge the code of both functions into one single function? Yes, they will execute sequentially, but, do you _actually_ care?

Comment: ^^ "Do you _actually_ care?" - What I mean is: I guess, you won't even notice that they execute sequentially, because they should execute really quick, don't they?

Comment: Can you help me with how?